# How to print all the swing components in a scrollable JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to print a form which consists of swing components which are in a scrollable `JFrame`. I have tried the below code to do it, but the print I get is only the scrolled area currently in the window. I need to print the whole page.

Code:

```
public int print(Graphics arg0, PageFormat arg1, int arg2) throws PrinterException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return 0;
    if (arg2 > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)arg0;
    g2d.translate((int)arg1.getImageableX(), (int)arg1.getImageableY());  

    float pageWidth = (float)arg1.getImageableWidth();  
    float pageHeight = (float)arg1.getImageableHeight();  

    float imageHeight = (float)this.getHeight();  
    float imageWidth = (float)this.getWidth();  

    float scaleFactor = Math.min((float)pageWidth/(float)imageWidth, (float)pageHeight/(float)imageHeight);  

    int scaledWidth = (int)(((float)imageWidth)*scaleFactor);  

    int scaledHeight = (int)(((float)imageHeight)*scaleFactor);    

    BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage( this.getWidth(),  this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
    Graphics2D gg = canvas.createGraphics();  
    this.paint( gg );    
    Image img = canvas ;  

    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null );  

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;  

}  

private void button4ActionPerformed() {
    // TODO add your code
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);
    boolean ok = job.printDialog();
    if (ok) {
        try {
             job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error printing: " + ex);
         /* The job did not successfully complete */
        }
    }
}
```

Also I need to hide some buttons and textFields from printing. (eg: "Print" button)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your best option is to draw the panes contents to a buffered image using `paint()`, and then print out the buffered image instead.

Comment: If you could provide lines of the code to be added,it would be a great help.I'm new to java and can't figure out the solution you have given. Thanks

Comment: Just replace the container inside JScrollPane with a custom one that overrides `paintComponent`: allocates a `BufferedImage` of its size (that's why you do not replace the content pane) and call `super.paintComponent(...)` twice: once with the same arguments, and once with `BufferedImage#createGraphics()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `this.paint( gg );` call `componentInTheScrollPane.paint(gg);`. Even better to call `printAll(gg);`

Comment: thanks.I tried calling printAll(gg); instead of the this.paint( gg );.But still only the scrolled area(visible content in the window) is printed.

Comment: You are probably calling print on the wrong container. By using "this.paint(gg)" it will only print the part of the layer inside the scroll pane that is viable. You instead need to call print on the container inside the scroll pane. The container is usually a `jPanel` or a `jLayeredPane`, and can be printed like so: `jPanel.paint(gg);` or `jLayeredPane.paint(gg);`. You will also need to replace `this.getHeight/Width()` with `jPanel/jLayeredPane.getHeight/Width()` else it still only print the viable size of the scroll pane.

Comment: For more help post your GUI creation code, so we can see how it all fits together.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to draw a jScrollPane to an image it will fail every time and only print the visible section. To get around this issue you need to instead draw the contents of the jScrollPane, ideally you will have a jLayer, jPanel or some other container inside the jScrollPane and can just draw that directly to an image like so:

```
Form (jPanel top container)
 -> jScrollPane
     -> jLayer/jPanel/container
         -> Contents (tables, buttons etc)
```

I wont give you code on how to print a whole form with an entire scrollPane, that requires some math and a little more code, but to get you started here is an example method that will draw the contents of a jLayer to a buffered image regardless if it is out of view in the jScrollPane, and then save that image to file: (I wont cover printing that is another issue)

```
private void button4ActionPerformed() {
    try
    {
        //get height/width from the jLayeredPane or jPanel inside the scroll pane
        int imageHeight = jLayeredPane.getHeight();
        int imageWidth = jLayeredPane.getWidth();

        //Draw contents of the jLayeredPane or jPanel inside the scroll pane (but not the scroll pane itself)
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
        Graphics2D gg = image.createGraphics();  
        jLayeredPane.paint(gg);

        //The "image" now has jLayers contents
        //Insert your code here to scale and print the image here
        //Some Code
        //In my example I have chosen to save the image to file with no scaling
        ImageIO.write(canvas, "png", new File("C:\\out.png"));
        //Some Code

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```